# Tutorial still shown despites being disabled

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I disabled tutorials from the Interface settings panel, as shown by the following screenshot.

[image: screenshot showing "tutorials" unchecked]

However, I still constantly get tutorials, which aren't even coherent (as this one shows an item within my closed inventory).

[image: screenshot showing tutorial popup over nothing]

Comment: Smells like addon interference. Try disabling addons. Also do Cache Interface WTF.

Comment: Fresh install, I have no installed addon

Comment: The screenshot host is being blocked by our company's security policy. You could avoid that by uploading them directly into your post, since other people might have the same problem as I have. And you never know when external hosts delete your files, which would more or less kill your question.

Comment: Done as you requested, it now goes through Imgur

Comment: You could try `/console SET flaggedTutorials 0` or if that doesn't help have you tried deleting your WTF folder?